# JavaScript : Fetch API vs AJAX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, fetch-api

I have this code:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Is using Fetch API for a request like in the code above considered as an AJAX request?

I a request considered an AJAX request only if we use the `XMLHttpRequest` object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are several ways to send Asynchronous requests like jQuery, axios, Fetch API or XMLhttprequest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

fetch is an ajax request.

but fetch is a simple api and have not, so I recommended [fatcher](https://github.com/fatcherjs/fatcher)

fatcher is a lightweight HTTP request library based on `fetch`, allows us to use native `fetch` for web requests in a browser and NodeJS environment.

It is wrapped using the native `fetch`, we require that browsers or NodeJS support `fetch` when we use it.

- Fetch support is already pretty good in modern browsers, so we don't have to worry about FETCH compatibility
- In NodeJS, fetch already has some support starting with '18.0.0'

Fatcher aims to embrace the `fetch` of the standard library and at the same time provide some functions that cannot be provided in `fetch`, as well as make the function better expand and reuse.

```
import { fatcher, isFatcherError } from 'fatcher';

fatcher({
    url: '/',
})
    .then(result => {
        // Response
        const { data, status } = result;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Catch Fatcher Error
        if (isFatcherError(err)) {
            // Request successfully. But response status code is not 2xx.
            console.error(err.toJSON());
            return;
        }

        // This is other errors.
    });
```